# Shaky Background in FireFox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have very simple transition that positions the background image (moving side to side) which works perfectly in chrome but "shakes" (best term to describe it) in FireFox.

Code is:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}

#animate-area   { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 170px; 
    background-image: url("../img/header.jpg");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    animation: animatedBackground 60s linear infinite;
}
```

and I tried this, however no joy:

```
var x = 0; var y = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
    $("#animate-area").css("background-position", x + "px " + y + "px");
    x++; y--;
}, 50);
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the shakes, it's flowing smoothly from left to right?

Comment: Does it occur in this pen when you view it in firefox? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKEXNR